Location of roots of $z+z^2/2+\cdots+z^n/n$
I am interested in the complex roots of $P_n(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{z^k}{k}$.
With the help of some computer algebra system, I have been able to see that, with the exception of the root $0$, all the roots seem to be distributed almost uniformly on a circle centered at the origin and with radius slightly larger then $1$.
I couldn't figure out why it is so ...
What are the proper tools needed to investigate that question ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Don't know if it helps but $\frac{d}{dz}P_n(z)=\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}$

Linking to this related question I recalled. Not a duplicate, but not too far off either.

For  $|z| < 1$, $P_n(z)/z$ converges, uniformly on compact sets, to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n-1}/n =  -\ln(1-z)/z$ (with removable singularity at $0$ removed) which has no zeros there, so by Hurwitz's theorem, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N$ such that for $n > N$, $P_n(z)$ has no zeros except $0$ with $|z| \le 1-\epsilon$.
For $|z| > 1$, let $w = 1/z$. $$ n w^n P_n(1/w) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n w^{n-k}}{k} = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{1-j/n} w^{j}$$
converges, uniformly on compact sets in $\{w: |w| < 1\}$, to $\sum_{j=0}^\infty w^{j} = 1/(1-w)$ which has no zeros there, and so again by Hurwitz, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N$ such that for $n > N$, $P_n(z)$ has no zeroes with $|z| \ge 1+\epsilon$.  Thus for large $n$ all zeros of $P_n(z)$ except $0$ are near the unit circle.

Polynomials generally "usually" have this behaviour, unless there is a reason to have roots away from the unit circle. The reasons for that are known but far from obvious: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182412/why-do-roots-of-polynomials-tend-to-have-absolute-value-close-to-1

@underflow I don't aim to explain the limit results you give in the comments. The question asks about polynomials, I answer about polynomials.

@underflow In fact, I am ready to agree with your evaluation of my answer, which is worded quite mildly. If you explain your comments in a separate answer, it will probably be more insightful than mine, and I'll happily +1 it.
